# Is it possible to print a log of all database queries for a page request in WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm making a plugin that does a custom query on the WordPress database, and then I'm looping through the results listing each post title as a link to the actual post.

I'm using `get_permalink($id)` to obtain the URI of each post, but since I'm doing this outside of the loop, my suspicion is each of these requests is making a separate database query.

I've checked out the function code and tried to follow what's going on in the actual WordPress core files, but what I'm really interested in is a general way to do this, so I can make sure I'm always writing the most optimized code in all of my plugins.

Is anyone aware of the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In wp-config.php add this line:

```
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

In your theme functions.php file (or a plugin file for that matter) you can use this:

```
add_action('shutdown', 'sql_logger');
function sql_logger() {
    global $wpdb;
    $log_file = fopen(ABSPATH.'/sql_log.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($log_file, "//////////////////////////////////////////\n\n" . date("F j, Y, g:i:s a")."\n");
    foreach($wpdb->queries as $q) {
        fwrite($log_file, $q[0] . " - ($q[1] s)" . "\n\n");
    }
    fclose($log_file);
}
```

Make sure `ABSPATH.'/sql_log.txt'` is writeble from php.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

I actually modified the function a bit since I was actually looking to have the query list printed out at the bottom of each page, but I wouldn't have figured it out without your example.

Comment: Thanks @Poelinca, I also have same question, But using that method I get only the SELECT queries, but not the INSERT/UPDATE queries. Any solution for this? Is it possible?

Comment: You can also just use WordPress's debug.log file instead of writing to a new file: https://pastebin.com/jDKbmSDQ Just make sure you have `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in wp-config.php.

Comment: I suggest to use for log file content uploads directory instead, that is writable. `$log_file = fopen(trailingslashit(WP_CONTENT_DIR) . 'uploads/sql_log.txt', 'a');`

Answer (score 5):

Can't comment on @Poelinca Dorin's answer, so I'll just say it here:

If you want to know what is launching your query just use this:

`fwrite($log_file, $q[0] . " - ($q[1] s)". " [Stack]: $q[2]" . "\n\n");`

instead of:

`fwrite($log_file, $q[0] . " - ($q[1] s)" . "\n\n");`